# Mapping spatial Distributions in R

Tags: r, dictionary, distribution, spatial

My data set includes 17 stations and for each station there are 24 hourly temperature values.
I would like to map each stations value in each hour and doing so for all the hours. 
What I want to do is something like the image.

[image]

The data is in the following format:

```
     N2     N3     N4    N5     N7     N8    N10    N12   N13    N14   N17   N19    N25    N28   N29    N31    N32
1 1.300 -0.170 -0.344 2.138  0.684  0.656  0.882  0.684 1.822  1.214 2.046 2.432  0.208  0.312 0.530  0.358  0.264
2 0.888 -0.534 -0.684 1.442 -0.178 -0.060  0.430 -0.148 1.420  0.286 1.444 2.138 -0.264 -0.042 0.398 -0.196 -0.148
3 0.792 -0.564 -0.622 0.998 -0.320  1.858 -0.036 -0.118 1.476  0.110 0.964 2.048 -0.480 -0.434 0.040 -0.538 -0.322
4 0.324 -1.022 -1.128 1.380 -0.792  1.042 -0.054 -0.158 1.518 -0.102 1.354 2.386 -0.708 -0.510 0.258 -0.696 -0.566
5 0.650 -0.774 -0.982 1.124 -0.540  3.200 -0.052 -0.258 1.452  0.028 1.022 2.110 -0.714 -0.646 0.266 -0.768 -0.532
6 0.670 -0.660 -0.844 1.248 -0.550  2.868 -0.098 -0.240 1.380 -0.012 1.164 2.324 -0.498 -0.474 0.860 -0.588 -0.324
  MeteoSwiss
1       -0.6
2       -1.2
3       -1.0
4       -0.8
5       -0.4
6       -0.2
```

where N2, N3, ...m MeteoSwiss are the stations and each row presents the station's temperature value for each hour.

```
id  Longitude   Latitude
2   7.1735          45.86880001
3   7.17254         45.86887001
4   7.171636    45.86923601
5   7.18018         45.87158001
7   7.177229    45.86923001
8   7.17524         45.86808001
10  7.179299    45.87020001
12  7.175189    45.86974001
13  7.179379    45.87081001
14  7.175509    45.86932001
17  7.18099  45.87262001
19  7.18122  45.87355001
25  7.15497  45.87058001
28  7.153399 45.86954001
29  7.152649 45.86992001
31  7.154419 45.87004001
32  7.156099 45.86983001
MeteoSwiss  7.184    45.896
```

Comment: The first task is to convert your data to long format and then to merge in the latitude and longitude values for the appropriate "id"'s. Then it would be easy for lattice xyplot or one of the ggplot2 plotting functions to give you the multi-panel output. You could wait for someone to construct R data objects, but it would make more sense to to replace those screen output versions with dput() versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I define a toy example more or less resembling your data:

```
vals <- matrix(rnorm(24*17), nrow=24)
cds <- data.frame(id=paste0('N', 1:17),
                  Longitude=rnorm(n=17, mean=7.1),
                  Latitude=rnorm(n=17, mean=45.8))
vals <- as.data.frame(t(vals))
names(vals) <- paste0('H', 1:24)
```

The `sp` package defines several classes and methods to store and
display spatial data. For your example you should use the
`SpatialPointsDataFrame` class:

```
library(sp)

mySP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=cds[,-1], data=data.frame(vals))
```

and the `spplot` method to display the information:

```
spplot(mySP, as.table=TRUE,
       col.regions=bpy.colors(10),
       alpha=0.8, edge.col='black')
```

[image: spplot.points]

Besides, you may find useful the `spacetime` package
([paper at JSS](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v51/i07)).